# Sum of exactly n perfect square divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, square-numbers

I'm doing a Number Theory question, and if someone could offer a hint, that would be greatly appreciated;

The question is: **Find the sum of the perfect square divisors of the smallest integer with exactly 6 perfect square divisors.**

My reasonings:

- My method so far has been simply listing out pairs of possible exponents that are multiples of 2, and listing them out, or using combinations to calculate the total number of combinations. Obviously, this brute-force method is not working out well, and if anyone could provide a hint, that would be greatly appreciated.
- I know how to find the *product* of all divisors, but not their sum. Furthermore, how would one "target" only perfect square divisors? Perhaps complementary counting?

Comment: the **smallest** number with exactly six square divisors is going to be a square itself. Try the first several squares, see what happens

Comment: Do you know how counting the number of divisors of a number given its prime decomposition works? It's not too difficult to adjust to square divisors.

Comment: Of course, because the only possible exponents can be 1, and 2, which would result in a square.

Comment: @DarkRunner the exponents can also  be 4, 6,...

Comment: Yes, it's the product of the sum of 1 added to each exponent of the prime factorization. However, how would you target that for square numbers?

Comment: For example, $2^{10}$ has $6$ perfect square divisors: $1,2^2,...,2^{10}$

Comment: So basically just divide the exponent in half+1? That seems to hold for larger integers.

Comment: You can have more than one prime factor!  if $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then the number of square divisors of $n$ is $\prod \left(1+\lfloor \frac {a_i}2\rfloor\right)$.

Comment: So, basically, I can set $(\frac { { a }_{ 1 } }{ 2 } +1)=2,\quad (\frac { { a }_{ 2 } }{ 2 } +1)=3$(I don't have GIFunction), right? Since they're the only integers to have a product of 6?

Comment: Greatest Integer is formatted via "\lfloor ... \rfloor".  $6=2\times 3$ or $1\times 6$.  A priori it might not be entirely obvious which gives the smallest $n$ (though I think it is fairly clear that $2^{10}$ is not minimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversation in the comments is correct, but I would suggest the following approach. First we find the lowest number with exactly $6$ divisors, and then we square that number. This squared number will then have exactly $6$ square divisors.

To find the number, we use the number of divisors formula
$$d\left(\prod p_i^{a_i}\right) = \prod(a_i +1)$$
Now the divisors of $6$ are $6,1$ and $2,3$, so now we choose the lowest primes and attach these exponents to them as follows.
$$2^5=32 \quad 2^2*3=12$$
Now we have the lowest number with exactly $6$ divisors, $12$. So the lowest number with 6 square divisors is $144$. The square divisors are the squares of the divisors of $12$, so now we add those up to get our answer.
$$1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+6^2+12^2=210$$

Comment: Problem asks for sum, not product, of square divisors.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll fix that.

Comment: Wow; so essentially working backwards towards the solution.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have *exactly* $6$ square divisors, a number $n$ is either of the form $n=p^{10}m$ with $p$ a prime and $m$ square-free or of the form $n=p^4q^2m$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes and $m$ square-free. In the first case the square divisors sum to $1+p^2+p^4+p^6+p^8+p^{10}$ and the smallest possibility is $n=2^{10}=1024$. In the second case the square divisors sum to $1+p^2+q^2+p^4+p^2q^2+p^4q^2$ and the smallest possibility is $n=2^4\cdot3^2=144$. So $n=144$ is the smallest possibility, and the sum of its square divisors is $1+4+9+16+36+144=210$.